# Dired format on Linux and Windows (dired-listing-switches)

Tags: dired, microsoft-windows

I'm using the following on Linux:

```
(setq dired-listing-switches "-agho --group-directories-first")
```

and the files show like this:

```
  -rw-r--r--. 1 2.1K Mar 16 03:19 test.org
  -rw-r--r--. 1  316 Mar 11 18:00 test.rec
  -rw-r--r--. 1 2.5K Mar  3 13:01 test.tex
```

however on Windows the user is display along with "None" and the date format is different:

```
  -rw-r--r--. 1 zoliky None  59 03-16 03:19 test.org
```

On Windows "dired" there is a username shown "zoliky" plus "None". How can I remove those two? Also I would like the file size in human readable form, just like on Linux. I want the date to be `Mar 3` instead of `03-16`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On MS Windows, there's no corresponding notion of a group.

But you can use `ls` option `G` to remove the Group column.

E.g., `C-u C-x d SOME-DIRECTORY` will list that directory without showing a Group column.

This works even with `ls-lisp`, which is what Emacs uses on MS Windows.